# Python 3: Socket server send to multiple clients with sendto() function

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, python-3.x

I have a server set up with sockets and threading, and when I connect multiple clients to it, if a client sends a message, the server repeats that same message back to it, instead of to all other connected clients. For example:

```
#server terminal
Server is connected on 8000
('127.0.0.1', 50328) is Connected
('127.0.0.1', 50329) is Connected
Received Message b'hi\n'

#Client 1 terminal
#input
[user1]hi
#returns:
[user1] b'hi\nhi\n'[user1]

#Client 2 terminal
#doesn't return anything, just sits at the prompt
[user2]
```

The relevant code for the server is:

```
def clientHandler():
    c, addr = s.accept() 
    print(addr, "is Connected")
    if addr not in clients:
        clients.append(addr)
    try:
        while True:
            data = c.recv(1024)
            if not data: 
                break 
            print("Received Message ", repr(data))
            for client in clients:
                c.sendto(data, client)
    except:
        print("Error. Data not sent.")
```

I have read the following sources, but to no avail:

[python tcp server sending data to multiple clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21690683/python-tcp-server-sending-data-to-multiple-clients)

https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html

What must I do to make it send user1's message to all other users through the server?

Edit 1:
All server.py code:

```
from socket import *
from threading import Thread

clients = []

def clientHandler():
    c, addr = s.accept() 
    print(addr, "is Connected")
    if addr not in clients:
        clients.append(addr)
    try:
        while True:
            data = c.recv(1024)
            if not data: 
                break 
            for client in clients:
                c.sendto(data, client)
    except:
        print("Error. Data not sent to all clients.")

HOST = '' #localhost
PORT = 8000

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(5)

print("Server is running on "+ str(PORT))

#Thread(target=clientHandler).start()
#Thread(target=clientHandler).start()
#Thread(target=clientHandler).start()

for i in range(5): 
    Thread(target=clientHandler).start()

s.close()
```

Comment: Are you using multiple threads for each new client? If so, please show us the relevant code for that as well

Comment: if it actually sent the data to all clients, wouldnt you end up in an infinite sending loop? receive data --> send to all hosts --> they all receive data --> send it to all hosts again, and so on?

Comment: Im not sure. The way I send data to all clients from the server is by using the for loop. I would think that once it runs through all possibilities in the clients list it would stop. No?

Comment: Its a client/server model, I do not think client would be sending back everything they receive. Server is the one that is sending the data to multiple clients, not the other way round ,I guess

Comment: yes that is correct. my server is the one that receives data from client 1 for example, and then has to send that data to every other client in the clients list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a few issues in your code -

1. You are starting clientHandler threads, but then you are not making the main thread join any , this may cause main thread to die before the child threads finish processing, I think you would want to save the `Thread` objects you create to a variable and then make them join the main thread.
2. Instead of making the clientHandlers directly, you should first wait for accepting a connection from client (outside the handler function) and once you get the connection, add it to list of clients and send it over to the clientHandler.
3. In your code - `for client in clients: c.sendto(data, client)` m this sends data to all clients ,instead you should check if `client` is not the `client` that this thread is servicing, by checking against the `addr` that this thread is servicing.

Example changes -

```
from socket import *
from threading import Thread

clients = []

def clientHandler(c, addr):
    global clients
    print(addr, "is Connected")
    try:
        while True:
            data = c.recv(1024)
            if not data: 
                break 
            for client in clients:
                if addr != client:
                    c.sendto(data, client)
    except:
        print("Error. Data not sent to all clients.")

HOST = '' #localhost
PORT = 8000

s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
s.listen(5)

print("Server is running on "+ str(PORT))

#Thread(target=clientHandler).start()
#Thread(target=clientHandler).start()
#Thread(target=clientHandler).start()
trds = []

for i in range(5): 
    c, addr = s.accept() 
    clients.append(addr)
    t = Thread(target=clientHandler, args = (c, addr))
    trds.append(t)
    t.start()

for t in trds:
    t.join()

s.close()
```

Comment: this seems to work up to a point. Now, it simply return the message to the client that sent it, not to the other clients

Comment: Are you sure you are using the complete code i pasted? including the changes to the clientHandler() function? its a `!=` , not `==`

Comment: can you put a `print` statement before the sendto function for `addr` and check wat address it sends to?

Comment: the first client outputs this: ('127.0.0.1', 50835) and the second ('127.0.0.1', 50836)

Comment: and that client's address is?

Comment: ithose are the addresses for each client respectively

Comment: Are you 100% sure that only the current client is recieving the messagE?