# Send messages received by server to multiple clients in python 2.7 with socket programming

Tags: python, sockets, server, client, chat

So I have created a socket program for both client and server as a basic chat. I made it so the server accepts multiple clients with threading, so that is not the problem. I am having trouble sending messages to each client that is connected to the server. I am not trying to have the server send a message it created but rather have `client1` sending a message to `client2` by going through the server. For some reason it will only send it back to `client1`.

For example, `client1` will say hello and the server will send the same message back to `client1` but nothing to `client2`. I fixed this slightly by making sure the client doesn't receive its own message but `client2` is still not receiving the message from the `client1`.

Any help will be appreciated.

I have tried multiple changes and nothing seems to work. You can look at my code for specifics on how I did things but ask if there are any questions.

Also, there is a question where someone has asked that is similar and I thought it would give me an answer but the responses stopped going through and a solution was never fully given, so please don't just refer me to that question. that is located here: [Python 3: Socket server send to multiple clients with sendto() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31086366/python-3-socket-server-send-to-multiple-clients-with-sendto-function).

Here's the code:

**CLIENT:**
    import socket
    import sys
    import thread

```
#Create a socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

#Enter username to identify self to others
name = raw_input("Enter username: ") + ": "

#Connect socket to ip and port
host = socket.gethostname()
#host = '192.168.1.10'
server_address = (host, 4441)
sock.connect(server_address)

#function waiting to receive and print a message
def receive(nothing):

    while True:

        data = sock.recv(1024)
        if message != data:
            print data

# Send messages
while True:
    #arbitrary variable allowing us to have a thread
    nothing = (0, 1)

    message = name + raw_input("> ")
    sock.sendall(message)

    #thread to receive a message
    thread.start_new_thread(receive, (nothing,))
```

**SERVER:**

```
import socket
import sys
import thread

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# Bind the socket to the port
host = socket.gethostname()
server_address = (host, 4441)
sock.bind(server_address)

#Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(5)
print "Waiting for connection..."

#Variable for the number of connections
numbOfConn = 0

#Name of list used for connections
addressList = []

#Function that continuosly searches for connections
def clients(connection, addressList):

    while True:

        message = connection.recv(1024)
        print message

        #connection.sendall(message)
        #for loop to send message to each
        for i in range(0,numbOfConn - 1):
            connection.sendto(message, addressList[i])

    connection.close()

while True:
    #accept a connection
    connection, address = sock.accept()
    print 'Got connection from', address
    numbOfConn += 1
    addressList.append((address))

    #Thread that calls the function: clients and stores them in a tuple called connection
    thread.start_new_thread(clients, (connection, addressList))


sock.close()
```

Please help me if you can!

**EDIT:**

I was able to fix it to a certain extent. It is still a little buggy but I am able to send messages back and forth now. I needed to specify the connection socket as well as the address. Here's the updated code:

**SERVER**

```
import socket
import sys
import thread

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# Bind the socket to the port
host = socket.gethostname()
server_address = (host, 4441)
sock.bind(server_address)

#Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(5)
print "Waiting for connection..."

#Variable for the number of connections
numbOfConn = 0

#Name of list used for connections
addressList = []
connectionList = []

#Function that continuosly searches for connections
def clients(connectionList, addressList):

    while True:
        for j in range(0,numbOfConn):
            message = connectionList[j].recv(1024)
            print message

            #for loop to send message to each
            for i in range(0,numbOfConn):
                connectionList[i].sendto(message, addressList[i])

    connection.close()

while True:
    #accept a connection
    connection, address = sock.accept()
    print 'Got connection from', address

    numbOfConn += 1
    addressList.append((address))
    connectionList.append((connection))

    #Thread that calls the function: clients and stores them in a tuple called connection
    thread.start_new_thread(clients, (connectionList, addressList))


sock.close()
```

Comment: for i in range(0,numbOfConn - 1):
numbOfConn is 2 which creates a range(0,1) which returns just 0.

Comment: That's not the problem. I've tried both ways but the reason it is like that is so that it calls the first and second address in addressList which is placed in the 0 and 1 mark respectively. That's why the range is from (0,1)

Comment: Actually, that was part of the problem (still don't know why), but not the only one. I was able to fix it. Ill include it in the edit.

Comment: It gets a bit more tricky when clients unexpectedly close. You need to be able to handle that, possibly by checking to see if anything has been sent within a duration then close the socket, decrement the count, etc.

Comment: Have a look at this. Seems quite elegant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20745352/creating-a-multithreaded-server-using-socketserver-framework-in-python